# Align text under list of images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, menu

I have a page with a menu in the middle, and inside of the menu there are images correctly aligned in a ul, however I want to add text under every image but when i try, the text for some reason end up in the middle all the way to the right of the menu, why? also it feels like I should just remove all the javascript code and start from scratch and use the simpler option to implement my images in html file instead. I've been sitting up for 10 straight hours designing my website and learning so i might just be tired but any help is appreciated.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Map Gallery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylemaps.css">
    </head>

    <body onload="document.body.style.opacity='1'">

        <header>
            <h1>Map Gallery</h1>
        </header>
        
        
        <div class="menu">
            <ul id="imageList"></ul>
            
        </div>
        <div class="mappages">
            <a href="#" id="chapter1">Chapter 1</a>
            <a href="#" id="chapter2">Chapter 2</a>
            <a href="#" id="chapter3">Chapter 3</a>
            <a href="#" id="chapter4">Chapter 4</a>
        </div>

        
        <script src="fadeAnim.js"></script>
        <script src="mapscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-image: url("../images/background-maps.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;

    /*animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;*/
}
/*@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
     }
}*/



.menu{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:55%;
    height: 100%;

 
}


.menu ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu li{
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.menu img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
   
    
}



h1{
    
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red, 0 0 0.5em blue, 0 0 0.1em blue;

    margin: auto;
}
```

js:

```
const chapter1 = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 49; i++){

chapter1.push({src: `../images/maps/chapter1/${i}.jpg`, alt: `Map ${i}`});
}
const chapter2 = [{src: '../images/maps/76.jpg'}]; //not used yet
const chapter3 = [{src: '../images/maps/64.jpg'}]; //not used yet
const chapter4 = [{src: '../images/maps/98.jpg'}]; //not used yet

// Function to display images for the chosen chapter
function showImages(chapter) {
    document.querySelector('#imageList').innerHTML = '';

    // Loop through the images in the selected chapter
    chapter.forEach(image => {
      
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = `<img src="${image.src}" alt="${image.alt}">`;
      document.querySelector('#imageList').appendChild(li);
    });
  }

  // Add click event to the Chapter 1 link
  document.querySelector('#chapter1').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showImages(chapter1);
  });

  // Add click event to the Chapter 2 link
  document.querySelector('#chapter2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showImages(chapter2);
  });

  document.querySelector('#chapter3').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showImages(chapter3);
  });

  document.querySelector('#chapter4').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showImages(chapter4);
  });

  showImages(chapter1);
```

Comment: If it's your own project - use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/) for grid implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stckoverflow @ginger, I made some corrections and placed the sample text under the image.

```js
const chapter1 = [{src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558383331-f520f2888351?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OHx8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'},
{src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558383331-f520f2888351?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OHx8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'}];
/*for (let i = 1; i <= 49; i++){

chapter1.push({src: `../images/maps/chapter1/${i}.jpg`, alt: `Map ${i}`});
}*/
const chapter2 = [{src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1616020453784-a24fa9845b05?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'}]; //not used yet
const chapter3 = [{src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561336313-0bd5e0b27ec8?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'}]; //not used yet
const chapter4 = [{src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612528443702-f6741f70a049?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'}]; //not used yet

// Function to display images for the chosen chapter
function showImages(chapter) {
    
    const img_list = document.getElementById('imageList');
    img_list.replaceChildren();// equal to innerHtml = '';
    // Loop through the images in the selected chapter
    chapter.forEach(image => {
      
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = image.src;
      img.alt = image.alt;
      li.append(img);
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.textContent = "Image Title";
      li.append(span);
      img_list.appendChild(li);
    });
  }

  // Add click event to the Chapter 1 link
  document.querySelector('#chapter1').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showImages(chapter1);
  });

  // Add click event to the Chapter 2 link
  document.querySelector('#chapter2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showImages(chapter2);
  });

  document.querySelector('#chapter3').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showImages(chapter3);
  });

  document.querySelector('#chapter4').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showImages(chapter4);
  });

window.onload = function(){
  document.body.style.opacity = 1
  showImages(chapter1);
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-image: url("../images/background-maps.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;

    /*animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;*/
}
/*@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
     }
}*/



.menu{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:55%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:10px;
 
}


.menu ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu li{
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    
}
.menu li span{
  padding:5px;
}
.menu img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
   
    
}
h1{
    
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red, 0 0 0.5em blue, 0 0 0.1em blue;

    margin: auto;
}
.mappages{
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Map Gallery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylemaps.css">
    </head>

    <body onload="document.body.style.opacity='1'">

        <header>
            <h1>Map Gallery</h1>
        </header>
        
        
        <div class="menu">
            <ul id="imageList"></ul>
            
        </div>
        <div class="mappages">
            <a href="#" id="chapter1">Chapter 1</a>
            <a href="#" id="chapter2">Chapter 2</a>
            <a href="#" id="chapter3">Chapter 3</a>
            <a href="#" id="chapter4">Chapter 4</a>
        </div>

        
        <script src="fadeAnim.js"></script>
        <script src="mapscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```